# Convert ASCII in XML to readable SQL varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this syntax to read XML into a table:

```
SELECT date, time, phonenumber
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'orders/mail/order')
WITH 
(
date [varchar](20) 'date',
time [varchar](20) 'time',
phonenumber [varchar](20) '../set[@id="c"]/set[@id="adr"]/set[@id="billing"]/property[@id="8"]'
)
```

In the XML there is this value:

```
<![CDATA[ 0494&#47;12 34 56 ]]>
```

Which contains the ASCII 47 which needs to be converted into a slash.  Of course there are many other special characters.  Is there a way to easily get this in the correct format?

Comment: It not clear what you mean. XML uses Unicode, not ASCII. `<![CDATA[ 0494&#47;12 34 56 ]]>` isn't a value; it's markup. The value is " 0494&#47;12 34 56 ". "&#47;" looks like markup too, but, by virtue of it being in a CDATA section, _it is not._ Presumably, this was intended by the XML document author.

Comment: It might be the intention of the XML document author that the value be HTML markup. (HTML also uses Unicode, not ASCII.) Unless you know, how can you handle it properly?

Comment: @TomBlodget the text 0494&#47;12 34 56 should be 0494/12 34 56 char 47 in ASCII is a slash.

Comment: XML uses Unicode: [digits up to the terminating `;` provide a decimal representation of the character's code point {in ISO/IEC 10646/Unicode}.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-references). HTML uses Unicode: [Decimal numeric character reference…a base-ten integer that corresponds to a Unicode code point](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) Presumably, if you wanted to just hack it, you'd REPLACE &#47; with /. But to do it better, you have to know the intent of the XML document author. If the intent is HTML, T-SQL isn't the best tool. Maybe SQL-CLR.